# Application monitoring performance in scala

Tags: performance, scala, profiling

I have a web service written in scala and built on top of twitter finagle RPC system. Now we are hitting some performance issues. We have external API components and database layer.
I am planning of installing Zipkin in order to have a service level tracing system. This will allow me to know where the bottleneck is at the service level.

I am wondering though if there are framework out there to monitor the performance inside my application layer. The application is a suite of filters that are applied consecutively to my data and I would like to know which filter take time to compute. I heard about JVM profiling but it seems a little overkill for what I want to do. What would you recommend ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Well before starting digging into JVM stuff or setting up all the infrastructure needed by Zipkin you could simply start by measuring some application-level metrics.

You could try the library [metrics](https://github.com/codahale/metrics) via this [scala api](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala).

Basically you manually set up counters and gauges at specific points of your application that will help you diagnose your bottleneck problem.